# Table Column Highlight with Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table and I would like to control it's highlight with only radio button.
But when I change selector to only input:radio doesn't work. Only works with th selector in my sample.

```js
$("th").on("click", function () {
  var $currentTable = $(this).closest("table");
  var index = $(this).index();
  $currentTable.find("td").removeClass("selected");
  $currentTable.find("tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td").eq(index).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  width: 5em;
}
.selected {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="options" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="1" /></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It does work if clicked on actual radio button rather than the background. If I were you - I'd consider involving the values of `th` e.g. If `1` clicked then do this.. if `2` clicked, do this.

Answer (score 2):

When switching to radio-buttons you have to listen to `change` event to determine when the button was really checked. Also `this` keyword will rely to the button, not to `th`, so you'll have to find `th` to get correct index.

See the example below:

```js
$("input[name='test']").on("change", function () {
  var $currentTable = $(this).closest("table");
  var index = $(this).closest('th').index();
  $currentTable.find("td").removeClass("selected");
  $currentTable.find("tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td").eq(index).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  width: 5em;
}
.selected {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="options" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="1" /></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was

`var index = $(this).index();`

You are getting index value of input. But you need parent of input index value. You need change to

`var index = $(this).parent().index();`

Note: You can use `clicks` events but i think "change" event more useful.

```js
$("input[name='test']").on("change", function () { // clicks works aswell. But for radio / checkbox inputs you can add change event callback 
  var $currentTable = $(this).closest("table");
  var index = $(this).parent().index(); // We need parent' index. 
  $currentTable.find("td").removeClass("selected");
  $currentTable.find("tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td").eq(index).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  width: 5em;
}
.selected {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="options" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="1" /></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what changes you made and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.